# myMediaPlayer.getDuration(); shows an error

Tags: android, android-studio

Why does `myMediaPlayer.getDuration();` show an error?

[image: image description here]

```java
songTextLabel.setText(songName);
songTextLabel.setSelected(true);
        
position= bundle.getInt("pos",0);
Uri u=Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
        
myMediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
        
myMediaPlayer.start();
songSeekbar.getMax(myMediaPlayer.getDuration());
```

Comment: please add debug data

Comment: please explain what are you doing and image does not have error to show